# php echo variable xml

Tags: php, xml

I would like to print a variable in a method post xml text.
Is possible?

```
<?
$qtdRows = 10; //Ver consulta do banco
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
//ARQUIVO XML CRIADO NO SERVIDOR (Pode ser um arquivo em branco, so para iniciar, e depois ele coloca o conteudo com o script)
$arquivo = "cases.xml";

$escrever .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>';
$escrever .= '<filmes>';

    for($i=0; $i<$qtdRows; $i++){
        $escrever .= '<filme>';
        $escrever .= '<nome> $nome </nome>';
        $escrever .= '<ano>$ano</ano>';
        $escrever .= '<diretor>$diretor</diretor>';
        $escrever .= '<comentarios>$filme</comentarios>';
        $escrever .= '</filme>';
    }
$escrever .= '</filmes>';

$fd = fopen ($arquivo, "w"); // abre o arquivo
fwrite($fd, $escrever); //Escreve no arquivo
fclose ($fd); // fecha o arquivo

?>
<script>
    location.href = 'index.php'; //Redirediona, depois de gerado o XML, para qualquer pagina (Ex: index.php)
</script>
```

this method does not work!
What would the correct syntax? `$escrever .= '<nome> $nome </nome>';`

Comment: Please enable error reporting to the highest level when you write code. Then fix all notices, warning and if you got them, errors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$escrever .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>';
```

for:

```
// Without concatenation
$escrever = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>';
```

Also, the concatenation should be:

```
$escrever .= '<nome>' . $nome . '</nome>';
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`.` is used to concatenate strings, as shown here.

```
$escrever .= '<nome>' . $nome . '</nome>';
```

(Add the dots `.` and the single quotes `'`.)

Suerte!

Comment: I do believe `'<nome>$nome</nome>'` would correctly print the contents of `$nome` with PHP

Comment: Not woking! The output file is: <nome>. $nome .</nome>
<ano>2002</ano>
<diretor>Fernando Meirelles</diretor>
<comentarios>Filme mu ito bom!!</comentarios>

Comment: Then `$nome` probably isn't set, you'd have to check `isset( $_POST['nome'] )` and it's contents too, prior to the loop.

Comment: @MackieeE - PHP variables are not parsed in single-quoted strings.